# Posting to facebook page from php script

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm using this code to post to my user profile page, it's working good when posting to my profile (I set in the $id my facebook user id), but when I try to post to my facebook page (not my profile page) I set in the $id the facebook page id then the script doesn't work anymore and I got the following error

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

This  is my code

```
<?php
class Facebook
{
    /**
     * @var The page id to edit
     */
    private $id = '<FACEBOOKPAGEID>';

    /**
     * @var the page access token given to the application above
     */
    private $app_access_token = "<MYAPPACCESSTOKEN>";
    /**
     * @var The back-end service for page's wall
     */
    private $post_url = '';
    /**
     * Constructor, sets the url's
     */
    public function Facebook()
    {
        $this->post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $this->id .'/feed';
    }
    /**
     * Manages the POST message to post an update on a page wall
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return string the back-end response
     * @private
     */
    public function message($data)
    {
        // need token
        $data['access_token'] = $this->app_access_token;
        // init
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->post_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        // execute and close
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        // end

        return $return;
    }
}
$facebook = new Facebook();
echo "<pre>";
echo $facebook->message(array( 'message'     => 'Message',
                          'link'        => 'http://www.mylink.com/',
                          'picture'  => 'http://www.mylink.com/pic.jpg',
                          'description' => 'My description' ) );
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

I'm using app_access_token because it doesn't change and I don't need to be logged in facebook to be able to post to my facebook page

Any idea about why this is working for my profile page and not for my facebook page?

Comment: Probably because you need to use an access token with manage_pages permissions. Inspect the access token using the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and make sure manage_pages is enabled by the access token.   See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922011/easy-example-posting-message-on-page-as-page/12924269#12924269