# easy example posting message on page as page

Tags: facebook, api

Today I tried almost everything with the Facebook API. I'm using the PHP SDK. It worked out to log in as a user, as a page and as an app.

I have made the most simple login system as possible now:

Login.php

```
$app_id = "xx";
$app_secret = "xx";
$my_url = "continue.php";
session_start();   
// TOESTEMMING VRAGEN
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
if(empty($code)) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection
    $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
    . $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=manage_pages";
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}
```

At continue.php I have this code:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] === $_REQUEST['state'])) {
    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=" 
    . $params['access_token'];

    $accounts = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
    print_r($accounts);
} else {
    echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
}
```

I'm getting the login, I can give access, but when I continue I get this message:

> stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [message] => An active
>   access token must be used to query information about the current user.
>   [type] => OAuthException [code] => 2500 ) )

What I try to achieve is: On an admin part of my website I want to create a dialog where administrators can post updates to a facebook-page as a page-account. I also tried to login as an app, but I don't know if that's the right solution.

I can't find a tutorial on the web about which approach is needed for which solution. The advantage of logging in as an app, is that administrators don't need to have a facebook account. But can I (as an app) post an update to a facebook-page?

Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Thanks.

Comment: Where is your code for posting to a page?

Comment: I didn't even came that far, because everytime there was something with authentication... Like an active access token in my message above.

Comment: An access token is the way of Facebook to identify your request. Did you get one ? Did you assign it to $params['access_token'] ? If both answers are positive, show us the code, because based on the error message, there is obviously a problem with the access token.

Comment: as in @Alon_A's comment, plus check out this [answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3627684/facebook-graph-api-posting-to-fan-page-as-an-admin/7649048#7649048).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. These are all methods where I need a facebook user. I want to create a solution where the admins of the website doesn't has to have a facebook account, but can log in directly as a facebook page or app. So he can post messages to the page wall as a page or app.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete. I suggest you re-read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

Before you can get the Page Access Token, you need the User Access Token

```php
   if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] === $_REQUEST['state'])) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $_SESSION['access_token'] = $params['access_token'];

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     echo("Hello " . $user->name);
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, indeed it's incomplete. But that's because I didn't get the result I wanted. Is it possible to login as a page or as an app without having facebook? At this moment I am creating a website. The website also has a facebook page. But not all admins do have facebook. Is this possible to login (via PHP) as page or app at all, and then post something on the page's wall?

Comment: If you use a page token via a user token from a valid user on Facebook who is an admin of your page, it can work. See this http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/getting-your-facebook-page-on-your-website-with-access-tokens/ which shows how to display page posts without having to constantly authenticate.

Comment: Maybe I can use this process... But the example is getting information from Facebook. I want to login at my website as a page and post to the page's wall like a facebook as a page, not as an individual. I don't know if it's possible at all.

Comment: @p3sn you cannot login to Facebook as a page (except under the case of a business account) so yes that's not possible. You **need** a Facebook user at some point during the process.

Comment: What's the difference then between a business-account-page and a page I created from my personal account? I thought I could create page's (as an individual) for a business too. #confused

Comment: Business accounts are for advertising. They have limited uses. All that's important for this question is that since you cannot login as a page on Facebook.com without logging in as a user, you cannot do otherwise in an application.

Answer (score 0):

Basic example to post on a Page you own (posting as the Page):

Make sure user/page_owner has auth'd the app and is logged in (usual FB API methods).  User must have `manage_pages` (admin) permissions for the page.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(... );
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Get the page access token:

```
$page_id = 123456;
$page_info = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'?fields=access_token');
```

Use the page access token to post to your Page:

```
if (!empty($page_info['access_token'])) {
  $args = array(
    'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
    'message' => 'Testing SDK !',
  );
  $post_id = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed', 'post', $args);
  error_log('successfully posted post id '.$post_id);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  error_log('caught exception: '. $e);
}
```

If you still get an access token error, log the *user* access token and test/paste the user access token in the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and verify `manage_pages` perms is enabled.

See also this helpful [blog post on Page permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/524/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already replied phwd too. I'm searching for a solution to login as app (wich I tried once succesfull too). But is it possible to post on the page's wall as an app too? I want to login as app, because not all administrators of the website do have facebook. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot post on a Page as an App.

Comment: Hmm okay, that clears things up. So I can forget logging in as an app. Thanks!